# How to read rows and columns from text file in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have the following text file and I'm writing a program in visual basic and I want to use the numbers in the text file and set them to individual integers. 
the text file represents a hole table and contains x-y location and hole size. the number of holes (rows) can vary. 
[image: text file]

Comment: Don't post pictures of code or text files.  They are text.  Notice how your question is text?  That means you can post text directly.

Comment: As for the issue, your question is too broad for an actual answer, i.e. you haven't shown that you've made any effort on your own behalf, which is required before posting questions here.  If you do some research into reading delimited files in VB.NET, which you should have done already, you'll find that one option - probably the best option - is the `TextFieldParser` class.

Comment: If your file is your dataset, have you looked into treating it as such, you can set up data source connections to text files, if it has a fixed column width setup this should be relatively straightforward.  If this is your first time doing this I recommend experimenting with ODBC/OLEDB connection strings via a .UDL file.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the number by using following code

```
Dim reader as StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(filetoimport.Text)
Dim a as String

Do
   a = reader.ReadLine
   --code to skip the header--
   if [skip header condition] then
    positionX = a.substring(positionX,lenght)
    positionY = a.substring(positionY,lenght)
   end if
Loop Until a Is Nothing

reader.Close()
```